# SwiftUI on macOS, how can I make the whole row clickable?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a list of strings I want to render into a `List` of clickable buttons.

However, with my code below, only the text of the row is clickable when I'd like the whole thing to be.

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here but I'd love some help.

Thanks!

```
            List {
                ForEach(sites, id: \.self) { site in
                    Button(action: {
                        self.selectedSite = site
                    }) {
                        // TODO: Make this whole row clickable.
                        HStack {
                            Text(site)

                            if let selectedSite = self.selectedSite, selectedSite == site {
                                Spacer()
                                Button(action: self.removeFromList) {
                                    Text("Remove")
                                }
                                .background(Color.black)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .cornerRadius(6)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                    .padding(.vertical, 8)
                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                    .font(.system(size: 15))
                    .foregroundColor(selectedSite == site ? .white : .white)
                    .background(selectedSite == site ? Color.blue : nil)
                    .cornerRadius(6)
                }
            }
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that when `selectedSite` is nil, then you only show the `Text(site)` in the `HStack`... you're missing the all-important `Spacer()`. You'll notice the problem if you add a `.background(Color.red)`.

```
HStack {
    Text(site)

    if let selectedSite = self.selectedSite, selectedSite == site {
        Spacer()
        Button(action: {}) {
            Text("Remove")
        }
        .background(Color.black)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .cornerRadius(6)
    }
}
.background(Color.red)
```

| No `selectedSite` | `selectedSite` exists |
| --- | --- |
| [image: 3 rows, each with a Text that has a hugging red background] | [image: One of the rows are selected and has a red background that takes up the entire row's width] |

See how when there is no `selectedSite`, the `HStack` (red area) is tiny and only takes up the space of the `Text`? But then, when there *is* a `selectedSite`, the `HStack` expands to fill the entire row? To fix, try the following:

1. Move the `Spacer` *outside* the `if let selectedSite`, so that it's always there.
2. Use [`contentShape`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/contentshape(_:eofill:)) to make the area occupied by the `Spacer` clickable.

```
HStack {
    Text(site)
    Spacer() /// 1.
    if let selectedSite = self.selectedSite, selectedSite == site {
        Button(action: {}) {
            Text("Remove")
        }
        .background(Color.black)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .cornerRadius(6)
    }
}
.contentShape(Rectangle()) /// 2.
```

Result (tested on iPhone, but should be same result on macOS):

[image: Clicking different roles in the middle blank space works]

<sup>[Code for above demo](https://gist.github.com/aheze/d062f9fae42b8c2e62084606e90dcf94)</sup>

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working, unfortunately.

Comment: Ah! That pesky spacer. Thanks @aheze!

Comment: @ZackShapiro np! And thank you for making Better Programming a great place to write.